# React native," too many re-renders" when calling api in a loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

So what i want to do, to sum it up, is to call an api key multiple times with different variables added to it and add the objects returned into an array. However when i try to make a for loop, which loops through the different variables for the api-key. I get the error, "Too many re-renders, react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

for loop:

```
  const getCoinMarketDataApi = useApi(
    coinMarketDataApi.getCoinMarketData,
    true
  );

  const top10 = ["bitcoin", "storm", "cardano", "bogged-finance"];

  for (let i = 0; i < top10.length; i++) {
    getCoinMarketDataApi.request(top10[i]);
  }
```

The function called:

```
export default useApi = (apiFunc, addToArray = false) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  //Loading marketdata
  const request = async (...args) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await apiFunc(...args);
    setLoading(false);
    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

    setError(false);

    if (addToArray) {
      response.data[0].index = index; //Add the variable index to the array
      var newArray = [...data, response.data[0]]; //
      setIndex(index + 1);
      setData(newArray);
    } else {
      setData(response.data);
    }
  };
  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

I have no idea how to work around this, any input is appreciated, thanks for reading:)

Answer (score 1):

This might help

- Have an integer count of API calls loading. IsLoading: IsLoading + 1 and then show the loading indicator if IsLoading > 1
- Name each of your IsLoading differently to show different loading indicators. For example, if you had a call to get students and a call to get teachers, you would have IsLoadingStudents and IsLoadingTeachers and have separate loading indicators for each component in the app

Answer (score 0):

maybe u have too many useState.

try using only one state like this.

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
data:[],
error:false,
loading:false,
index:0
});

setState({...state,loading:true});
setState({...state,data:[],loading:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make any API calls inside a loop, very bad practice, see if API accepts a list of inputs

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for, thank you! https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/
This is the Api i'm using, how do i know if it supports multiple inputs? and if it does what would that syntax look like, {"banana", "apple","kiwi"} ?